# Remote Debugging Hosted Lua

Tags: debugging, lua

I am using Lua 5.3, hosting it in a C++ application. The C++ application provides various functions to a running Lua script. I would like to allow users to debug their Lua, while it is running in my application. I believe this is possible, but I can not find any recent information on doing this, only for older versions of Lua and this does not seem to work.

Can anyone please help me to get debugging a Lua script running under my application up and running? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that I know of is to use ZeroBrane's remote debugging capabilities. [Their document](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-remote-debugging) explains it pretty nicely, but for the sake of self-containment:

- Set your embedded Lua's path/cpath to zerobrane's stuff, or copy the `mobdebug.lua` file to your sources.
- Add `require('mobdebug').start()` to the beginning of your code
- You should be able to debug now. After you start your program, breakpoints set in the Lua sources should get hit.

This approach works best if you use ZB to edit your Lua files, which implies using a different editor for the C++ part. I found this to work reasonably well in practice, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have downloaded ZeroBrane and tried this previously, but this did not work for me and I think the reason is that in their documentation where they say:

"Reference path to mobdebug.lua and luasocket using package.path and package.cpath"

they don't provide a link to luasocket. I have previously searched google for luasocket, even downloaded its source code, but I could not get it working.

Is luasocket packaged with ZeroBrane, or is there a (binary and lua) distribution I need to download from an external source?

Comment: @MariusMyburg It's a separate package, but I thought it comes standard with most lua distros. You should be able to install it with `luarocks` if that's not the case, or you can build it yourself.

Comment: luasocket is packaged with ZeroBrane Studio for all supported platforms (Windows/macOS/Linux) and for Lua versions 5.1-5.3, so you don't need anything else (assuming you can load luasocket library linked against a Lua interpreter). I'll update the documentation to make this clear.

Comment: Also, ZeroBrane Studio will edit c/cpp files as well and should also show functions from the C code in the outline.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko Great! Also since you're there I'd like to say thanks for the amazing work you've been doing! :)

Comment: Thanks guys. I must be doing something quite simple wrong, I will start afresh and I will take it step by step as in the ZeroBrane documentation and figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Bartek! I pushed the documentation update to mention that the modules are included with the IDE.